# Update database record based on the select query result

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to update the price column, if the date column contains today's date. Following is my code but it update one record only, even there are two records of same date.

**Code**

```
<?php   
    require('db.php');
    $tdate=date('Y-m-d');
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM marketplace_product WHERE splprice_from IS NOT NULL AND splprice_to IS NOT NULL';
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {

             if($row['splprice_from']==$tdate)
             {
                  print_r($row);
                 $ent=$row['entity_id'];
                 $updatePrice="UPDATE marketplace_product SET today_price=splprice WHERE entity_id=$ent";
                 $result = mysqli_query($con, $updatePrice) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                 if($result)
                     echo "Price updated for id".$row['entity_id'];
                 else
                     echo "Price not updated for id".$row['entity_id'];
             }
         }
    }

?>
```

**Print result**

```
    Array ( [entity_id] => 2 [mageproduct_id] => 531 [adminassign] => 0 [seller_id] => 14 [store_id] => 0 [status] => 2 [seller_product_code] => [seller_price] => 5000.00 [splprice] => 4000.00 [splprice_from] => 2017-04-22 [splprice_to] => 2017-04-28 [today_price] => 0.00 [seller_qty] => 0 [return_qty] => [stock_per_day] => [confirmed_qty] => [pending_qty] => [sold_qty] => [canceled_qty] => [sell_limit] => 4 [discount_price] => [seller_tax] => [vat] => [cst] => [gst] => [octroi] => [created_at] => 2017-02-27 17:12:17 [updated_at] => 2017-02-27 17:12:17 ) 
Array ( [entity_id] => 3 [mageproduct_id] => 532 [adminassign] => 0 [seller_id] => 13 [store_id] => 0 [status] => 2 [seller_product_code] => [seller_price] => 5000.00 [splprice] => 4000.00 [splprice_from] => 2017-04-22 [splprice_to] => 2017-04-28 [today_price] => 0.00 [seller_qty] => 0 [return_qty] => [stock_per_day] => [confirmed_qty] => [pending_qty] => [sold_qty] => [canceled_qty] => [sell_limit] => 6 [discount_price] => [seller_tax] => [vat] => [cst] => [gst] => [octroi] => [created_at] => 2017-02-28 09:47:38 [updated_at] => 2017-02-28 09:47:38 )
```

Above update query updates the price for `entity_id=2` not for `entity_id=3`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @linktoahref OP checks in the while loop if `splprice_from` is today and then updates the record using the `entity_id` (which, in the while loop is from the same record).

Comment: @TomUdding there are two rows has the same date. so i want to update the price of both records.

Comment: One of the reasons can be timezone mismatch.

Comment: @Jigar when i print the result it shows two records. But when run the update query it updates first record only.

Comment: Why can't you fire `UPDATE marketplace_product SET today_price=splprice WHERE splprice_from = DATE(NOW()) AND splprice_from IS NOT NULL AND splprice_to IS NOT NULL` ? No Select or loop is required I think.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jigar will try it. Same time i want the updated records to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear you have use same object **"$result"** for select and update query please update the name **"$resultUpdate"** for update query.

Comment: Nice catch. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` is using the result of Update query second time.